# Conditional index of a value referring to a foreign key

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with more than 20 million products.

The product table has an foreign key for the user who registered the product.

The foreign key to the user has an index, but I want to optimize (if possible) it.

I want to remove the products of users who are inactive in the system from the index. This corresponds to 20% of the products.

It is possible? Is it performatic?

Comment: I checked the numbers again: 
products of active users: 53,702,334
products of inactive users: 37,554,117 

Index has 46GB;

I'm thinking of creating a new column in the product table that will be false when the user of the product is inactive. Then I'll make her conditional on her. With this new information, will I have a good performance gain?

Answer (score 0):

Removing 20% of the index is not going to have that much of an impact on performance, I don't think.

In any case, this is problem.  The only way that you can remove the index is to `NULL` out the field that has the registered user.  Forgetting this information may not be a good idea.

Perhaps there are other ways to optimize performance, before trying to figure out how to do something that seems pretty hard and might have little gain.

Answer (score 0):

If the performance is very important to you you can think about saving the necessary information in the products table. E. g. adding a column that the user is inactive. But this has the negative impact that you have to keep this value updated, which could be troublesome.

Another solution might be [Materialized Views](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-creatematerializedview.html) which are supported since PostgreSQL 9.3. You can only store the relevant rows (and columns) into a materialized view. Since they are based on ordinary tables, you can optimize all requests as usual.